# On Submit display div based on radio button selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have multiple inputs on the same page. Based on the selection and once the user press "Submit" I would like to show the relevant divs and hide the ones that are not related to the selection.

I could implement the structure I wanted but can not get the jQuery to display the different values.

**Here is my code so far:**

```js
(function($) {
  $('#quiz_submit').click(function() {
    $('#quiz_submit').click(function() {
      if ($('input[type="radio"]').attr("id") == "option-one") {
        $('.a1').show();
        $('.a2, .a3').hide();
      } else if ($('input[type="radio"]').attr("id") == "option-two") {
        $('.a2').show();
        $('.a1, .a3').hide();
      } else($('input[type="radio"]').attr("id") == "option-three") {
        $('.a3').show();
        $('.a1, .a2').hide();
      }
    });
  });
})(jQuery);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="quiz__form">
  <li class="quiz__item">
    <input type="radio" id="option-one" name="quiz-selector">
    <label for="option-one">Question 1</label>
    <div class="check"></div>
  </li>
  <li class="quiz__item">
    <input type="radio" id="option-two" name="quiz-selector">
    <label for="option-two">Question 2</label>

    <div class="check">
      <div class="inside"></div>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="quiz__item">
    <input type="radio" id="option-three" name="quiz-selector">
    <label for="option-three">Question 3</label>

    <div class="check">
      <div class="inside"></div>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>

<input type="button" id="quiz_submit" class="submit-cta" value="SUBMIT">

<div class="a1">Answerof the questoon - One </div>
<div class="a2">Answerof the questoon - Two </div>
<div class="a3">Answerof the questoon - Three </div>
```

Comment: `$('#quiz_submit').click(function() {
    $('#quiz_submit').click(function() {` - really? are you sure this is correct? note: there's no element with ID equal to `quiz_submit` in the HTML you posted, could that be the problem (besides the click handler inside the click handler of course)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a `button` with `id=quiz_submit` in your HTML. You also have typos in the third and final condition.

```js
(function($) {
  $('#quiz_submit').click(function() {
    let checkedId = $('input[type=radio][name=quiz-selector]:checked').attr('id')
    if (checkedId == "option-one") {
      $('.a1').show();
      $('.a2, .a3').hide();
    } else if (checkedId == "option-two") {
      $('.a2').show();
      $('.a1, .a3').hide();
    } else if(checkedId == "option-three") {
      $('.a3').show();
      $('.a1, .a2').hide();
    }
  });
})(jQuery);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="quiz__form">
  <li class="quiz__item">
    <input type="radio" id="option-one" name="quiz-selector">
    <label for="option-one">Question 1</label>
    <div class="check"></div>
  </li>
  <li class="quiz__item">
    <input type="radio" id="option-two" name="quiz-selector">
    <label for="option-two">Question 2</label>

    <div class="check">
      <div class="inside"></div>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="quiz__item">
    <input type="radio" id="option-three" name="quiz-selector">
    <label for="option-three">Question 3</label>

    <div class="check">
      <div class="inside"></div>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
<input type="button" id="quiz_submit" value="submit"/>
<div class="a1">Answerof the questoon - One </div>
<div class="a2">Answerof the questoon - Two </div>
<div class="a3">Answerof the questoon - Three </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If your problem is that your jQuery isn't working, it may have to do with the fact that there isn't any way for your code to get run.

First you have a click function inside a click function, take away one of those. Secondly there is no button to for that click handler to even run. I can't see anything particularly wrong with the code, as those were the things that stuck out to me.

Let me know if you are still getting an error after fixing that.

Answer (score 0):

There's no element with the id quiz_submit in your html code.

Answer (score 0):

i just created a code for you.  that may be your answer.

```
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="quiz__form">
  <li class="quiz__item">
    <input type="radio" id="option-one" name="quiz-selector">
    <label for="option-one">Question 1</label>
    <div class="check"></div>
  </li>
  <li class="quiz__item">
    <input type="radio" id="option-two" name="quiz-selector">
    <label for="option-two">Question 2</label>

    <div class="check">
      <div class="inside"></div>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="quiz__item">
    <input type="radio" id="option-three" name="quiz-selector">
    <label for="option-three">Question 3</label>

    <div class="check">
      <div class="inside"></div>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>

<div class="a1" style="display:none">Answerof the questoon - One </div>
<div class="a2" style="display:none">Answerof the questoon - Two </div>
<div class="a3" style="display:none">Answerof the questoon - Three </div>
```

and jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $('input[type="radio"]').change(function(){
  if($(this).attr("id")=="option-one"){
    $(".a1").show();
    $(".a2").hide();
    $(".a3").hide();
  }
  if($(this).attr("id")=="option-two"){
    $(".a1").hide();
    $(".a2").show();
    $(".a3").hide();
  }
  if($(this).attr("id")=="option-three"){
    $(".a1").hide();
    $(".a2").hide();
    $(".a3").show();
  }
  });

});
```

and here is working fiddle.

[ClickHereForFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/y9qg0x4c/)

Comment: This seems to work, however I will need this to be triggered on submit button. Can this behavior be activated on pressing "submit?" Example : <input type="button" id="quiz_submit" class="submit-cta" value="SUBMIT">

Comment: sure you can do this.